# Rewrite Url using .htaccess or hook

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

I have custom template and in that custom template I'm filtering data according to dropdown. I'm using GET method for filter ths data.

If browser hit this url :-

```
http://localhost/about-fruad-new/search-providers/?industry%5B%5D=financial_services
```

I want to replace it by this url,

```
http://localhost/about-fruad-new/search-providers/?financial_services
```

Code I have tried so far,

```
function prefix_movie_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'search-providers/([^/]+)', 'index.php?page_id=65&industry=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'prefix_movie_rewrite_rule' );

function add_query_vars($aVars) {
    $aVars[] = "industry";
    return $aVars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

I tried with this code but it's not working. 
If this is possible through .htaccess please provide me a .htaccess solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule and `add_query_vars()` func both refer to `industry` whereas in your example URL the GET param is `industry%5B%5D`, which is the urlencoded version of `industry[]`.

Comment: I change in `add_rewrite_rule` and `add_query_vars()` in `industry` to `industry[]`.
But it's not working.

Comment: You should probably change them all to `industry`. Generally speaking the only reason for using `[]` in a variable name is as illustrated in your func above, where `$aAvars[] = "industry"` is shorthand for `array_push($aAvars, "industry");`